# Subwoofer not working in Dell Inspiron 7720

Tags: 14.04, dell

Could someone help me turn the built-in subwoofer on? I have Dell Inspiron 7720 laptop and Ubuntu 14.04.

My sound settings:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4liMS.png

```
lspci | grep -i "audio device"
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)

cat /proc/asound/card0/codec* | grep Codec
Codec: IDT 92HD91BXX
Codec: Intel PantherPoint HDMI
```

Can someone help me ?

Comment: How exactly do you check that your subwoofer works or not?

Comment: I didn't hear any sound from subwoofer, only from front speakers :(

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! What are your sound settings?

Comment: I'm just uploaded screen with my sound settings :)

Answer (score 5):

Firstly you will need to install alsa-tools & alsa-tools-gui from either the software center or from terminal.

```
sudo apt-get install alsa-tools alsa-tools-gui
```

Open HDAJackRetask

Select the **IDT 92HD91BXX** codec

Check the “Show unconnected pins” box (the internal speakers do not show as connected)

1. Remap 0x0d (Internal Speaker, which is your Front side) to Internal speaker.
2. Remap 0x0f (“Not connected”, which is the under-display speakers) to “Internal speaker”
3. Remap 0×10 (“Not connected”, which is the subwoofer) to “Internal speaker (LFE)”

Select **“Install boot override”** to save the settings to apply at boot time. **Reboot**. When it comes back, you should have full sound from all speakers.

Comment: March 5, 2017 - Just to confirm this activates the sub-woofer for the Dell Inspiron 17R 7720 SE in Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix, the remap of "0x0f" is not good in the Inspiron 17R.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run `alsamixer` in **Terminal** here you will be able to see if it's muted.

To unmute it, press <kbd>M</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be two types of audio configurations for Dell Inspiron 17 R 7720 : 4.1-system and 2.1-system. If you know nothing about under-display speakers this means that your model has 2.1 speaker configuration (front-edge speakers + subwoofer).

Using 5.1 configuration manual by StallionSA when you have a 2.1 will work but it will cause your system unable to produce any sound with some variety after auto-detect procedures (sometimes after reboot or after unplugging headphones). It occures since in 2.1 variant both 0x0d and 0x0f outputs are physically connected to the front speakers, thus interconnected.

**For proper work of headphones and subwoofer at Dell Inspiron 17 R 7720 with 2.1 speaker configuration:**

1. You need to have *alsa-tools* & *alsa-tools-gui* installed, for example with a console command *sudo apt-get install alsa-tools alsa-tools-gui*
2. Open HDAJackRetask
3. Select the IDT 92HD91BXX codec
4. Check the "Show unconnected pins" box

   a. To fix no sound issue (totally mute system) restoring defaults once on the go:

   - remap 0x0d to "Internal speaker" and uncheck its "Override"
   - remap 0x0f to "Not connected" and uncheck its "Override"
   - remap 0x10 to "Not connected" and uncheck its "Override"
   - click "Apply now" button

   b. To fix no sound issue (totally mute system) restoring defaults permanently during reboot:

   - click "Remove boor override" button
   - reboot your system

   c. To make subwoofer work (after your "Pin configuration" settings are back default)

   - leave 0x0d at "Internal speaker" and check its "Override"
   - remap 0x10 to "Internal speaker (LFE)" and check its "Override"
   - click "Apply now"
   - click "Install boot override" button