# problems with sound on samsung np550p5c

Tags: 14.04, sound, samsung, hda-intel

**I have two problems:**

1. I am unable to use 4-channel audio when viewing the movies with vlc.
   When checking the sound is also only two front channel played from all 4.
2. And also closed the subwoofer. This is a problem similar to this issue:
   [Subwoofer not working in Dell Inspiron 7720](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481547/subwoofer-not-working-in-dell-inspiron-7720)

Can anybody help?

**My data:**

My notebook is Samsung NP550P5C

```
$ uname-a
Linux samsung-np550-u 3.13.0-29-generic #53-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 4 21:00:20 UTC 2014 x86-64 x86-64 x86-64 GNU/Linux

$ lspci | grep Audio
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family) High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)

$ cat /proc/asound/card0/codec* | grep Codec
Codec: Realtek ALC269VC
Codec: Intel PantherPoint HDMI
```

Comment: The first problem I decided setting in the sound settings "Analog stereo output" instead of "Analog surround 4.0 exit" and unchecking "Mute sound".
Remains the second problem.