# Less Sound in Ubuntu, More in Windows. Why?

Tags: dual-boot, sound, speakers

I have dual boot laptop (DELL inspiron 15 7559). Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04. Sound is louder in my Windows 10 but in Ubuntu a clear less. Why is that? how to solve it?
Note: Don't tell me to increase my laptop sound because it is already full and so of youtube's and any other downloaded media's file.

Comment: Does it have a sub woofer?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix yes

Comment: With my old Dell Inspiron I had to configure it specially in Linux to utilize the Sub-Woofer whereas in Windows it's automatic. My new Dell also has a subwoofer but I haven't bothered because external monitor is piped into TV system with 100 watt subwoofer. Here's the link for the old Inspiron: https://askubuntu.com/questions/211201/how-to-activate-subwoofer-in-inspiron-17r/1018740#1018740

Answer (score 1):

Go to the sound settings, turn up application volume to max or enable sound over-amplification and be happy with very loud sound.

[image]