# Subwoofer not working in 13.10 on Asus N56DP

Tags: sound, 13.10, pulseaudio, asus

Currently have an Asus N56DP. Using an older answer I could get the subwoofer to work under 12.04 but after an upgrade to 12.10 that method stopped working.

```
lspci|grep -i audio
00:01.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Trinity HDMI Audio Controller
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH Azalia Controller (rev 01)


lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 1bcf:2883 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

A bit more info. the fix for the n56v series worked under ubuntu 12.04 to get the subwoofer working but was a bit wonky. The fix was the one that added these lines to /etc/rc.local:

```
echo 0x1e 0x99130112 > /sys/class/sound/hwC0D0/user_pin_configs
echo 1 > /sys/class/sound/hwC0D0/reconfig
```

and added this line to /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=asus-mode4
```

lastly, my 13.10 was arrived at by upgrading from 12.04 through each version to 13.10.

Comment: That link to that older question could be interesting. Could you link it?

Comment: There are two previous questions dealing with this. The first one is a generic "getting ubuntu running on an n56vz" which has an answer for making the subwoofer work: 

http://askubuntu.com/questions/232481/running-ubuntu-on-asus-n56vz/236728

The other is the previous version of this question, which the OP never updated: 

http://askubuntu.com/questions/379345/no-sound-from-sonic-master-sub-woofer-asus-n56dp/395085?noredirect=1#comment520321_395085

Comment: This may be related (did you try all solutions there?): http://askubuntu.com/questions/136968/how-to-make-the-internal-subwoofer-work-on-an-asus-g73jw

Comment: Yep tried everything there. no joy.

What sucks is that this used to work in 12.04, even if it was perfect.

Comment: Here's a few more links that might help:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/336026/asus-n56dp-sonic-master-subwoofer-not-working/360558#360558
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1040873
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/871808

Comment: Someone made a suggested edit that this machine is different from the N56VZ and the fixes for it won't work. BUT THEY DID. The same fixes for the N56VZ worked fine on my N56DP back in 12.04 before some change broke them on both the N56VZ and N56DP. I had 4.1 and 5.1 sound etc all that. Then that stopped working and then I upgraded all the way to 13.10. A lot of things that had been iffy or worked wrong (fn-F8 for video output etc, full screen video) were fixed byt 13.10 so the upgrade was worthwhile.

Comment: Here's the posting about it stopping working on the n56vz:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/260223/n56vz-subwoofer-not-working-anymore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also have an N56DP, the solution is actually simple (It works for me on Ubuntu 14.04, i don't know about other versions.) First undo all the other junk you did, No need of messing with any conf files. Download alsa-tools-gui, open hdajackretask, switch to the realtek card and select show unconnected pins.
Override the following:-
14- line out center
15- line out center
16- internal speaker lfe
17- internal speaker lfe
18- line out center
1a- line out front
1b- line out back
1e- spdif out

Note this config enables subwoofer to play the low frequency from the right speaker (this is the standard in windows) By messing around you can try other configurations (I have not tried them all) One configuration i particularly liked turned my mic input into a second headphone jack.

Answer (score 1):

That's working ASUS N550LF with a little variant because there is not the pin 17 :

```
Pin ID : 0x14 => Line Out (Center/LFE)
Pin ID : 0x15 => Line Out (Center/LFE)
Pin ID : 0x16 => Internal Speaker (LFE)
Pin ID : 0x18 => Internal Speaker (LFE)
Pin ID : 0x19 => Line out (Center/ LFE)
Pin ID : 0x1a => Line Out (Front)
Pin ID : 0x1e => SPDIF out
```

I'd installed boot override because when I did apply now I've got the error message that the device is busy

Comment: Thanks for the format I didn't find where is the code formating.