# Wha't kind of model I've to add in my alsa-base.conf file

Tags: 14.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi

I've several problem with my sound card as : No sound when the HDMI is plugged, External SubWofer and the laptop speaker didn't switch off when I plugged headphone. It's an ASUS N550LF with 14.04 Kubuntu distribution.

Several forum and skill exchnage site told That I've add my model at the end of this line in my /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf file

```
options snd-hda-intel model=
```

But I have no idea what to put in after " model".

For help, there is the ling of the alsa-info sript:
[Alsa-project : alsa-info Result](http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=53618ec8d0e02c2e95f67860994b7ba2b0a31340)

I fixed the Subwofer problem but that could occur some conflict
[External Subwofer doesn't work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/405408/subwoofer-not-working-in-13-10-on-asus-n56dp/539467#539467).

Comment: In modern kernels, the Realtek driver does not have models. The analog and HDMI outputs are two separate devices; this must be configured with PulseAudio.

Answer (score 0):

-The problem with HDMI may be solved with pavucontrol (install it if needed), and choosing default device in "output tab" (clicking green button)
-The problem with subwoofer may be solved by changing model as you suggest: your hda codec is Realtek ALC668 , and from this [page](http://git.alsa-project.org/?p=alsa-kernel.git;a=blob;f=Documentation/sound/alsa/HD-Audio-Models.txt) ,  searching ALC66x/67x/892,  you can try `ASUS` as model.

Answer (score 0):

according to [Alsa logs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sound/alsa/HD-Audio-Models.txt) you the models is not the name of laptops. you should test for example model=asus-mode1

and I think

`snd-hda-intel` is not correct
`snd_hda_intel` is correct

so use `options snd_hda_intel model=asus-mode4`