# Ubuntu 20.10 - No Sound, Audio Controller: <access denied>, 'Dummy Output'

Tags: sound, 20.10

My speakers work fine on windows, I've just been trying to get them working on Ubuntu but 'Dummy Output' is my only listed output device. I've reinstalled Ubuntu, gone down a few rabbit holes and I can't fix it. Any tips?

ALSA Info: http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=3f026652460a271930b3e5a3e1a3aea0620c7024

Version: Ubuntu 20.10

Device: Acer Swift 315-52

**Commands:**

```
aplay -l #1
```

```
alsamixer #2
```

```
alsamixer -c 0 #3
```

```
lspci -v #4
```

```
lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Audio #5
```

**Outputs:**

```
aplay: device_list:274: no soundcards found... #1
```

```
cannot open mixer: No such file or directory #2
```

```
invalid card index: 0
try `alsamixer --help' for more information #3 
#(outputs the same result even if a different index number is used (0,1,2,3,...))
```

```
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 255
    Memory at df1a8000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=16K]
    Memory at df180000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel #4
```

```
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller [0401]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio [8086:9d71] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio [1025:1272]
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
00:1f.4 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus [8086:9d23] (rev 21) #5
```

**Attempt 1:**

```
apt-get install git
git clone git://anongit.freedesktop.org/pulseaudio/pulseaudio
sudo apt install pavucontrol
```

No output devices listed in Pulse Audio Volume Control besides 'Dummy Output'.

**Attempt 2:**

```
pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload
pacmd list-cards
```

```
0 card(s) available.
```

No sound settings available in my Acer laptop bios to change

["Dummy Output" No sound in Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/914463/dummy-output-no-sound-in-ubuntu-16-04)

**Attempt 3:**

```
sudo chmod 666 /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
echo 'options snd-hda-intel model=acer-mode1' >> /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
sudo chmod 644 /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

[Wha't kind of model I've to add in my alsa-base.conf file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/547542/what-kind-of-model-ive-to-add-in-my-alsa-base-conf-file)

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1669330

To Undo:

```
sudo chmod 666 /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
sudo sed -i '$ d' /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
sudo chmod 644 /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

(Can also edit the file manually after chmod 666 and before chmod 644)

**Attempt 4:**

https://www.bobjohnson.com/blog/adventures-with-linux-installing-ubuntu-on-a-panasonic-toughbook-cf31/

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-output-speaker.conf
```

And then replace the sections outlined in the article and reboot

**Attempt 5:**

Comment: Welcome to Askubuntu. Please do a google search for `site:askubuntu.com dummy output` to review some of the answers that exist for this question. Then, please edit your question and let us know which of these solutions does or does not work.

Answer (score 1):

After Upgrading from 22.04 to 22.10 I had the same problem.

Running

```
sudo touch /usr/share/pipewire/media-session.d/with-pulseaudio
systemctl --user restart pipewire-session-manager
```

fixed the problem.